# Error with changing interior of the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code that activates a different workbook and modifies the color of a range in that workbook. I'm getting an error message on the With lines.

I've had past problems with the code modifying cells in the wrong workbook, but I think I figured that out using ActiveSheet. The error listed is "Application or Object-Defined Error", and I have no idea what is incorrect.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

    projname = Range("E17")
    projnum = Range("E19")

    Dim obook As Workbook

    Set obook = Workbooks(Replace(projname, " ", "") + ".xlsx")

    obook.Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("A99") = 6

    counter = ActiveSheet.Range("A99").Value

    If counter Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(globalcounter, 1), Cells(globalcounter, 8)).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

    Else
        With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(globalcounter, 1), Cells(globalcounter, 8)).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If

    counter = counter + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `globalcounter` and where is it declared/populated?

Comment: Where is this code written in? If it's in some sheet's code-behind, then `Cells` is implicitly `Me.Cells`, which makes `ActiveSheet.Range(Me.Cells(...), Me.Cells(...))` likely to throw error 1004, unless `Me` is also the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: my mistake, globalcounter should be changed to counter

Comment: @MathieuGuindon is there a way to use cells such that it does not default to Me.Cells? The actual cell range is dependent on counter. It is currently on a different sheet than the desired ActiveSheet

Comment: Yes there is: use an explicit `Worksheet` object as a qualifier. `With ActiveSheet`, then `With .Range(.Cells(globalcounter, 1), .Cells(globalcounter, 8)).Interior`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon after that change, I am still getting the error- Cells is still referring to the undesired sheet. I have confirmed that the sheet that I want is indeed ActiveSheet, but I am hoping for some way to change this.